# TSQL pulling records from two tables that are not in parity

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables, one contains a list of employees, the other contains a list of PO's.

The PO Table looks like:

```
PoID PO# Name             City     State
1    55  Jasons Company   Miami    FL
2    66  Mikes Company    NewYork  NY
3    77  Sallys Company   Dallas   TX
```

My Employees Table looks like:

```
EmployeeID  Name    Phone         Email    PoID
1           John    123-123-1233  j@j.com  1 
2           Alex    234-234-2344  a@a.com  1
3           Cindy   345-345-3455  c@c.com  2
4           Jessica 356-356-3566  j@j.com  3
```

Now if my SQL Select statement is this:

```
SELECT * FROM PO p
LEFT JOIN Employees e
ON p.PoID = e.PoID
```

It will return all records in my PO table and perhaps just the top entry of any employee associated with that record. I need the Names/Emails of all records associated to be pulled as well.

I'm not sure how I can accomplish this as I do not want duplicate PO entries but rather just a comma delimited list of any possible names/emails associated with that PO to pull up in two additional columns on my PO.

Hope it makes sense, if anyone has come across this your insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this query

```
SELECT p.*,
 STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Name
          FROM @Employees e1
          WHERE e1.PoID = p.PoID
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS Names
,STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Phone
          FROM @Employees e1
          WHERE e1.PoID = p.PoID
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS Phones
,STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Email
          FROM @Employees e1
          WHERE e1.PoID = p.PoID
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS Emails
 FROM @PO p
```

Result

[image]

Below you can see the entire script with test data

```
declare @po table(PoID int, PO int, Name varchar(100),City varchar(100),State varchar(100))

insert into @po
select 1,55,'Jasons Company','Miami','FL' union
select 2,66,'Mikes Company','NewYork','NY' union
select 3,77,'Sallys Company','Dallas','TX'

declare @Employees table(EmployeeID int, Name varchar(100),Phone varchar(100),Email varchar(100), PoID int)

insert into @Employees
select 1,'John','123-123-1233','j@j.com',1  union
select 2,'Alex','234-234-2344','a@a.com',1 union
select 3,'Cindy','345-345-3455','c@c.com',2 union
select 4,'Jessica','356-356-3566','j@j.com',3

SELECT p.*,
 STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Name
          FROM @Employees e1
          WHERE e1.PoID = p.PoID
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS Names
,STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Phone
          FROM @Employees e1
          WHERE e1.PoID = p.PoID
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS Phones
,STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Email
          FROM @Employees e1
          WHERE e1.PoID = p.PoID
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS Emails
 FROM @PO p
```

Comment: thank you this is exactly what i was researching in doing using `FOR XML PATH`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this.

```
DECLARE @PO TABLE (PoID INT, PO INT,  Name VARCHAR(20), City VARCHAR(20), State vARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @PO
VALUES
(1, 55, 'Jasons Company','Miami','FL'),
(2, 66, 'Mikes Company','NewYork','NY'),
(3, 77, 'Sallys Company','Dallas','TX')

DECLARE @Employees  TABLE (EmployeeID INT, Name VARCHAR(20), Phone VARCHAR(20), Email VARCHAR(20), PoID INT)
INSERT INTO @Employees
VALUES
(1,'John','123-123-1233','j@j.com',1 ),
(2,'Alex','234-234-2344','a@a.com',1),
(3,'Cindy','345-345-3455','c@c.com',2),
(4,'Jessica','356-356-3566','j@j.com',3)



SELECT 
    *, 
    STUFF ( (SELECT 
            ', '  + Name + '/' + Email 
        FROM 
            @Employees e WHERE e.PoID = p.PoID FOR XML PATH('') ) ,1,1,'') [names/emails]
FROM 
    @PO p
```

Result

```
PoID        PO          Name                 City                 State      names/emails
----------- ----------- -------------------- -------------------- ---------- -------------------
1           55          Jasons Company       Miami                FL          John/j@j.com, Alex/a@a.com
2           66          Mikes Company        NewYork              NY          Cindy/c@c.com
3           77          Sallys Company       Dallas               TX          Jessica/j@j.com
```

Comment: thank you for answering my question. I've already accepted the previous answer if I could do both i would. I'll see in yours you've combined names with emails which is interesting. Thank you.